# Can't parsing the right table with BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse the "Per Game" table from https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/GSW/2017.html, but can't get the table I want.

Here's my code:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/GSW/2017.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html')
soup.find('table', attrs={"id":"per_game"})
```

It just return nothing......

Comment: If there is Javascript involved, have a look at [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8049520/5276734) - you need more than just requests for JavaScript.